# Unchecking wrong item in CheckedListBox

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make an option, to remove all unchecked items in a checked listbox. Everything is going fine, but when I get 2 or more items with the same name, it goes wrong.

For example: I got 3 items in the listbox with the same name, with the first one checked.
Now I run the event, but now the last 2 are removed, and the first one is unchecked...

```
private void removeAllUncheckedProcessesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        if (clbInstant.Items.Count - i == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (clbInstant.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            clbInstant.Items.Remove(clbInstant.Items[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the debugger, it enters the loop, does `i++`, repeats the loop again, goes to the else, before the else, checkstate of `clbInstant(0)` is checked, the checkstate of `clbInstant(1)` is unchecked and `i` is 1. But after the else, I got 2 items remain, with both unchecked.
Now it runs the loop for the second last time, and it removes the last unchecked item, with the result of 1 unchecked item remain...

If I have items with different names, I got no problem at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try this instead.

```
    foreach(object itemChecked in checkedListBox1) 
    {
       if(checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(itemChecked))== CheckState.UnChecked)
          checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(itemChecked)
    }
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo :p sorted now, this should go through all list items and remove unchecked ones.

Comment: If I use it and I check 1 or more checkboxes, it does nothing.
When I check none, I get a 'InvalidOperationException was unhandled' message.

Comment: Remove the .CheckedItems from the foreach part.